# Editar não edita PHP

Tags: php, html

Código:

***EditNot***

```
<?php
include('../connection_open.php');

include_once ('../controller/NotControle.php');
include_once ('../model/Not.php');
include_once ('../DAO/NotDAO.php');

$controller = new Notifica($conn);

$id = "";
$InAtivo = "";
$DtInicio = "";
$DtFim = "";
$DsMsg = "";

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $results = $controller->listar($id);

    $InAtivo = $results->getativo();
    $DtInicio = $results->getini();
    $DtFim = $results->getfim();
    $DsMsg = $results->getmsg();

}
?>
 <html>
 <body>
    <form action="../controller/NotPrecontrole.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return valid();">
        <div class="row">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
          <input type="text" name="DsMsg" value="<?php echo $DsMsg; ?>"/>

                <input type="submit" class="round success small button" value="Aplicar"/>
                <a class="round secondary small button" href="Home.php">Voltar</a>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***NotPrecontrole***

```
<?php
include_once ('../connection_open.php');

include_once ('../model/Not.php');
include_once ('NotControle.php');
include_once ('../DAO/NotDAO.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$InAtivo = $_POST['InAtivo'];
$DtInicio = $_POST['DtInicio'];
$DtFim = $_POST['DtFim'];
$DsMsg = $_POST['DsMsg'];

$objNot = new Not();
$objNot->setid($id);
$objNot->setativo($InAtivo);
$objNot->setini($DtInicio);
$objNot->setfim($DtFim);
$objNot->setmsg($DsMsg);

$controller = new Notifica($conn);

if (!empty($id)){
    $objNot->setid($id);
    $controller->editar($objNot);
}

header ("location: ../view/home.php?id=".$id);

include_once ('../connection_close.php');

?>
```

***NotControle***

```
<?php

class Notifica{

private $conn;

   public function __construct($connec){
       $this->conn = $connec;
   }

   public function editar(Not $objNot){
        $dao = new NotDAO($this->conn);
        return $dao -> editar($objNot);
   }

   public function listar($id){
        $dao = new NotDAO($this->conn);
        return $dao -> listar($id);
   }

    public function ListaNot(){
        $dao = new NotDAO($this->conn);
        return $dao -> ListaNot();
    }
}

?>
```

***NotDAO***

```
<?php

class NotDAO{

private $conn;

public function __construct($connection) {
    $this->conn = $connection;
}

public function ListaNot(){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM esp35399');
    $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $not = new Not();
                $not->setid($row->ID);
                $not->setativo($row->InAtivo);
                $not->setini($row->InAtivo);
                $not->setfim($row->DtFim);
                $not->setmsg($row->DsMsg);
                $results[] = $not;
            }
        }
    return $results;
}

public function editar(Not $not){
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
            'UPDATE esp35399 SET DsMsg = :DsMsg, InAtivo = :InAtivo, DtInicio = :DtInicio, DtFim = :DtFim WHERE ID = :ID'
        );
        $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $not->getid(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':InAtivo', $not->getativo(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DtInicio', $not->getini(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DtFim', $not->getfim(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsMsg', $not->getmsg(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
    }
}

public function listar($id){
        $not = new Not();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM esp35399 WHERE ID = :ID'
        );
        $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $not->setid($row->ID);
                $not->setativo($row->InAtivo);
                $not->setini($row->DtInicio);
                $not->setfim($row->DtFim);
                $not->setmsg($row->DsMsg);
            }
        }
    return $not;
}
}

?>
```

***Not***

```
class Not{

private $id;
private $InAtivo;
private $DtInicio;
private $DtFim;
private $DsMsg;


public function setid($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
public function getid(){
    return $this->id;
}

public function setativo($InAtivo){
    $this->InAtivo = $InAtivo;
}
public function getativo(){
    return $this->InAtivo;
}

public function setini($DtInicio){
    $this->DtInicio = $DtInicio;
}
public function getini(){
    return $this->DtInicio;
}

public function setfim($DtFim){
    $this->DtFim = $DtFim;
}
public function getfim(){
    return $this->DtFim;
}

public function setmsg($DsMsg){
    $this->DsMsg = $DsMsg;
}
public function getmsg(){
    return $this->DsMsg;
}
```

***Home***

```
foreach ($controller->ListaNot() as $objNot){

    <p><?php echo $objNot->getmsg(); ?></p>

    echo '<a href="editNot.php?id=' . $objNot->getid() . '">Editar</a>';

}
```

O problema é que ao editar algo no `input "DsMsg"` na página **editNot** não está alterando no banco e continua me retornando a mesma coisa no `echo` na página **home** dentro do `foreach`. Não identifiquei o erro ainda. Parece que a função editar na *DAO* não está funcionando, porém as demais funcionam perfeitamente. Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: Debuga, imprima a query que foi executada para salvar o valor. A query vai mostrar onde está o problema, se está chegando o valor correto.

Comment: Dei um `print_r($objNot);` no NotPrecontrole e me retorna o que editei no `input DsMsg`, até ai chega pois no banco não edita sendo assim não aparece no `echo $objNot->getmsg();` na home já editado.

Comment: A condição de update está sendo satisfeita ?

Comment: Não funciona, os dados do input chega até no precontrol depois dai não acontece nada.

Comment: Resolva os notices e faça novos testes.

Comment: Agora me retornou esses erros na precontrole: 

`Notice: Undefined index: InAtivo in C:\xampp\htdocs\controller\NotPrecontrole.php on line 9`

`Notice: Undefined index: DtInicio in C:\xampp\htdocs\controller\NotPrecontrole.php on line 10`

`Notice: Undefined index: DtFim in C:\xampp\htdocs\controller\NotPrecontrole.php on line 11`

Comment: Ok, já resolvi porém continua na mesma.

Comment: Imprime a query e nos mostra ela como exemplo aqui.

Comment: Qual query você precisa ? Não entendi. Que tipo de informação queres para me ajudar ?

Comment: Gostaria de ver a query sql que usaste para salvar os registros editados.

Comment: Única query sql que uso é essa ai da função editar é esta que você precisa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, no meu banco de dados a coluna ***InAtivo*** é uma ***primary key*** Not Null.

Sendo assim eu não estava passando valor nem um para ela no ***UPDATE***.

Criei mais um `input` no *editNot* passei o valor pelo `input` e editou tudo.

```
<input type="text" name="InAtivo" value="<?php echo $InAtivo; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lá onde tem o hidden field, tente não usá-lo, sempre achei ele meio problemático.
Quando eu tenho q passar esse tipo de valor 'id', ou eu passo por um botão:

```
<button type="submit" name="meu_botao" value="minha_id_variavel">editar</button>
```

ou via url na na chamada do form:

```
<form action="pagina.php?id='sua_id_variavel'" method="post">
```

ai no segundo caso, no php vc recebe assim:

```
$_GET['id'];
```

Particularmente eu prefiro o segundo caso, via url, pois vc tem uma url pra cada pagina que o php gerar, fica mais fácil pra algum buscador fazer referências das suas páginas separadamente ;)

espero ter ajudado o//